# SQL performance impact on multiple columns in constraint or unique index

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I created a table in postgres that includes various columns that based on an import from a csv. Since the csv can be re-uploaded with some changes and I don't want the re-upload to create duplicates on rows that didn't change, I added a constraint and unique index with majority of the columns included in them. Is there any performance concerns to doing this? Is there a better way to solving this?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_a (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    table_b_id SERIAL REFERENCES table_b(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    column_a INT,
    column_b INT,
    column_c BOOLEAN,
    created_time BIGINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "table_a_key" UNIQUE ("table_b_id", "column_a", "column_b", "column_c")
);
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: a foreign key column should never be defined as `serial`, that just doesn't make sense. `serial` is just a shorthand ("macro") for `integer not null default nextval('some_seq')` - why would you want a default value taken from a sequence for a foreign key column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - thanks for pointing this out, so table_b_id should actually be int? I just kept it the same type as what was in table_b for column id

Comment: Yes, `table_b_id` should be `int` which **is** the same type as the referenced table. If you use the more modern `identity` columns instead this is more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an index always imposes a performance penalty for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements as the index needs to be maintained.

However, in most cases the added overhead doesn't really matter and might be out-weighted by the improved performance when SELECTing data. The performance overhead is more clearly visible when doing bulk loads compared to single row operations.

But if you want to prevent duplicates, you don't have a choice to begin with.

The only reliable way to prevent duplicates is to create a unique constraint (or index) as you did. It's also the only way you can make use of an "upsert" using `insert ... on conflict ...`

So, yes there is a performance penalty to pay. And no, there is no better way to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: If you update column `b` on a table that has an index on column `a`, does the index impose overhead?  Similarly, if a column that is indexed is inserted with a `NULL` value does that impose a performance penalty?